# iPad retina images - Why use two different image sizes?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, ipad, retina-display

For iPad Retina (or iPhone Retina as well), why do we need to have two types of image sizes and add a suffix like @2x for the retina version?

Can't we just have one type of retina resolution images and for devices that do not have retina display, let the device handle resizing the image to smaller (non-retina) size?

Comment: Because some people here think you should have searched on this before posting, as I'll guess there are a dozen previous postings almost the same. Anyway +1 as its a reasonable question to ask (i asked the same on an Apple forum :-)

Comment: Thanks David. I really did search for it. All the answers were telling what to do, how to do, not why..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resizing takes time and memory. And resizing while retaining sharpness is hard to do. Which algorithm do you use? Bicubic or bilinear? "But this icon looks better when resized with *other-algorithm-here*!" How is iOS meant to know that the 1px border you drew is still meant to be a 1px border at half the resolution?

Comment: Also: Why should already slow devices do even more work? And what about old iOS versions which have never heard of retina display before?