# Images size for an iPad app

Tags: ios, image, retina-display

I'm developing an iPad app with lots of multimedia content and I want it to work both on retina and non-retina display iPads.

I would like to know if I have to include every single image that will appear in retina and non-retina resolutions like this:

`image1.png` 1024x768 Standard resolution for fullscreen iPad image.

`image1@2x.png` 2048x1536 Retina resolution for fullscreen iPad image.

Wouldn't it be enough with the retina resolution and if the app detects that it's running on a non-retina device, then shrink it? It seems to work that way in the simulator.

I'd like to keep the size of the app as low as possible and I don't think that duplicating all the image assets will help.

Comment: Think this should be on Programmers SE, but whilst I'm here creating the higher resolutions assets and scaling down seems a good idea, although you'll want to look out of aliasing (which with a resolution being halved, will probably happen).

Comment: @OMGtechy do you mean [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Yes :) Also, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549318/ipad-retina-images-why-use-two-different-image-sizes?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should sacrifice the app size in order to have better memory performance on non-retina devices.