# Different image sizes for iOS development

Tags: ios, iphone, image, resize, retina-display

According to this [link](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html), would I need four different version of the same image size? Originally, I only created one for the iPhone 5, and I used the autosizing feature on storybuilder to resize the image correctly on iPhone 4s and below.

Answer (score 0):

**Concerning the four resolutions** (***@2x.png): As it is described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1 you have to resize some images, for example the App Icon has to be high- and low-resolution,

> If you need to support standard-resolution iPhone or iPod touch devices

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

For the other Images, it is not necessary, but as "ta.speot.is" described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12549329/1113407 it is better if you do it yourself.

And "JustSid" comment

> Why should already slow devices do even more work?

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12549329/1113407)

put it straight: The older devices which do not support retina display are slower and at most times (own experience) your app won't run fluently on those if you do not prepare the app.

**Concerning the iPhone 5 vs iPhone 4S**:
You need some images in both heights, as it is mention in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1. 
As the iPhone 4S has got the Apple A5-Chip and doesn't have to resize the image, as it has got an retina display, other images don't have to be resized. Therefor you could use the storybuilder-feature... But you have to ask yourself if the app should run on an older, non ratina display device...